# Diodon not launching at startup

Tags: xubuntu, startup, autostart, startup-applications, clipboard-manager

I'm currently using Xubuntu 14.04 and I have Diodon set to start automatically (under Session and Startup, I go to the 'Application Autostart' tab and I've made sure that the box for "Diodon (GTK+ clipboard manager)" is ticked. Nevertheless, the application does not launch automatically at system startup. 
I can launch the application manually (via whisker menu or terminal) and it works fine. Any ideas why the app won't start automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple workaround. I gave up on Diodon's attempt to make enable autostart by default so I unticked the box and instead added I new autostart application using "diodon" as the command to launch it. Now diodon starts up after booting the system.

Answer (score 1):

Your session cache might be stale. Try clearing it:

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Select `Session and Startup`
3. Select the `Session` tab
4. Click the `Clear saved sessions' button

Now logout and log back in, and see if Diodon starts.

Comment: It didn't work. I tried logging out and back in and I also tried clearing it again and then reboot. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint, what works for me is to open the System Monitor.  Right click on Diodon.  Change the priority to Very High.  Reboot.  Then this extremely convenient program runs on startup.  WFM.